# error occurred while installing ovirt-engine-sdk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to update an old app (Rails 5) on a new computer...
This gem (ovirt-engine-sdk) keep failing (it's not in my gemfile it must be a dependencie of another one... Acually I don't know what it is... ( Iam not coding for years but  I need to fox this old app)..

Here is my Gemfile :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '3.2.2'

gem 'bootsnap', require: false
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'puma'
gem 'rails', '5.2.1'
gem 'redis'

gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.3'
gem 'sprockets-rails', :require => 'sprockets/railtie'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 5.0.9'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'webpacker'
gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'mail_form'
gem 'meta-tags'

gem 'devise' 

gem 'fog'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.3'
#gem 'mimemagic'
gem 'file_validators'

gem 'react-rails'

gem 'photoswipe-rails'
gem 'faker', '~> 1.9', '>= 1.9.1'


gem 'geocoder'

gem "recaptcha", require: "recaptcha/rails"
gem 'sitemap_generator'

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  #gem 'pg', '~> 1.4', '>= 1.4.6'

end

group :development, :test do
    gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.7'
    gem 'launchy'
    gem "chromedriver-helper"
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
    gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 3.1'
    gem 'capybara'
  #gem 'capybara-webkit'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
end
```

And here is the error...

```
my_app      gem install ovirt-engine-sdk -v '4.4.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'                                   [(3.2.2)]
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ovirt-engine-sdk:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.4.1/ext/ovirtsdk4c
/Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for xml2-config... yes
checking for curl-config... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.4.1/ext/ovirtsdk4c
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20230419-45054-gbeemt sitelibdir\=./.gem.20230419-45054-gbeemt clean

current directory: /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.4.1/ext/ovirtsdk4c
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20230419-45054-gbeemt sitelibdir\=./.gem.20230419-45054-gbeemt
compiling ov_error.c
compiling ov_http_client.c
ov_http_client.c:216:29: warning: excess elements in array initializer [-Wexcess-initializers]
        .reserved = { NULL, NULL }
                            ^~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/stddef.h:89:16: note: expanded from macro 'NULL'
#  define NULL ((void*)0)
               ^~~~~~~~~~
ov_http_client.c:272:39: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    count = INT2NUM(context_ptr->size * context_ptr->nmemb);
            ~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ov_http_client.c:392:33: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'long' and 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
        while (pointer - buffer < length && isspace(*pointer)) {
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~
ov_http_client.c:651:18: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    ptr->limit = connections;
               ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
ov_http_client.c:845:71: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    context_ptr->code = curl_multi_wait(context_ptr->handle, NULL, 0, timeout, NULL);
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                               ^~~~~~~
ov_http_client.c:1001:47: warning: incompatible function pointer types passing 'int (VALUE, VALUE, struct curl_slist **)' (aka 'int (unsigned long, unsigned long, struct curl_slist **)') to parameter of type 'int (*)(VALUE, VALUE, VALUE)' (aka 'int (*)(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long)') [-Wincompatible-function-pointer-types]
        rb_hash_foreach(request_ptr->headers, ov_http_client_add_header, (VALUE) headers);
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/include/ruby-3.2.0/ruby/internal/intern/hash.h:83:40: note: passing argument to parameter 'func' here
void rb_hash_foreach(VALUE hash, int (*func)(VALUE key, VALUE val, VALUE arg), VALUE arg);
                                       ^
ov_http_client.c:1092:34: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') and 'int' [-Wsign-compare]
    if (RHASH_SIZE(ptr->pending) < ptr->limit) {
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~
ov_http_client.c:1118:71: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') and 'int' [-Wsign-compare]
        while (RARRAY_LEN(ptr->queue) > 0 && RHASH_SIZE(ptr->pending) < ptr->limit) {
                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~
8 warnings generated.
compiling ov_http_request.c
ov_http_request.c:75:29: warning: excess elements in array initializer [-Wexcess-initializers]
        .reserved = { NULL, NULL }
                            ^~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/stddef.h:89:16: note: expanded from macro 'NULL'
#  define NULL ((void*)0)
               ^~~~~~~~~~
ov_http_request.c:347:77: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rb_cData'
    ov_http_request_class = rb_define_class_under(ov_module, "HttpRequest", rb_cData);
                                                                            ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
make: *** [ov_http_request.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.4.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/nelly/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/extensions/arm64-darwin-21/3.2.0/ovirt-engine-sdk-4.4.1/gem_make.ou
```

thanks